# how to style div (element) which class name contains string

Tags: html

i wanted to use css to style an object which class or id name contains a specific word.

i used javascript but now need css solution.

//p.s. my javascript code is below. it tried to get id of specific classname and style it(after 3 seconds of pageload):

```
<script src="ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">

        var t=setTimeout(function(){
            var clasnamee = "form-field";
            var whatcontains = "copy";
            var myla = document.getElementsByClassName(clasnamee);
            var arylengh = myla.length;

            for (var i = 0; i < arylengh; i++) {

                var kk = document.getElementsByClassName(clasnamee)[i].id;
                if(kk.indexOf(whatcontains) > - 1)
                {
                 $("tr#" + kk).css("background-color", "#BCB4B4");
                // or try with jQuery
                //jQuery("tr#" + kk).css("background-color", "#BCB4B4");

                }
            }

        },3000);
        </script>
```

Comment: If the ids are unique, why do you use "tr#" and not just "#"?

Answer (score 1):

here is a method to style css element contains a specific word(string).

if ID contains blabla:

```
div[id*="blabla"] 
{
    background-color:#BCB4B4;
}
```

*(you can use not only for div, but for table, input, label,textarea or any other variations too:*

```
input[class*="blabla"] 
{
    background-color:#BCB4B4;
}
```